# How can i make the user to enter limited text in a text box?

Tags: asp.net

in my application (asp.net) i have a filed ( phone code) and  it contain a text box. and i want to restrict the user to enter only 4 letter after that the cursor should not print any character how can i write the code can u help me thank you

Comment: 4 letters or 4 characters?. All the answers below limit up to 4 characters, regardless whether it is alphabet or number or space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'maxLength' property.

```
<asp:textbox maxlength="4" runat="server" />
```

Full msdn documentation on the property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

For an HTML text box

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" runat="server" id="txt1" />
```

For an asp.net text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
```